# Sqoop jar deprecated

Tags: java, eclipse, sqoop

I am developing an application for data syncing between Hive and Teradata.
For this I am using sqoop in embedded mode, i.e. I have added sqoop as a jar in the classpath and use Sqoop.runTool(..) to execute the operation.

However on eclipse it is marked as deprecated. I using version 1.4.2 and could not find any information on this.

I'm currently using it anyway but it would be better if somebody could provide some information as to why it is deprecated and what could be done about it?

Comment: What is the "it" that is marked as deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what precise class are you using? There are currently two Sqoop classes:

- com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop - this is deprecated
- org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop - this is the right one to use

Sqoop was historically developed mainly at cloudera and it got moved under Apache later (during version 1.3.0). During incubation (before version 1.4.0) we moved all the functionality from cloudera namespace into apache namespace. We've provided classes in cloudera namespace to keep backward compatibility, but we marked them as deprecated.

Jarcec

Comment: Thanks!
So i guess just changing the namespace should work. I've kept the scope as "provided" in pom and I load the jar directly from sqoop's installation directory into the classpath.